# Google API PHP Client and Codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-cloud-platform, google-api-php-client

I want to include Google Cloud in one of my webprojects which is based on Codeiginiter.
Now my big question is, how to implement the Google API PHP client into CI?
Since CI is a MVC framework it wouldn't make sense including it directly with `require_once` in the view, so I thought about creating a library but that means a lot of work.
Does anyone know a better solution or maybe a fitting CI library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be implemented by creating a simple library by extending the Google_Api 
some thing like..

```
require_once /path/to/Google_Api/file_name.php

Class my_google_api extend Google_Api
{
    // constructor 
}
```

Now load this library to your controller and the access all the methods from Google_api

Comment: Do you mean, that I've to include the 'autoloader.php' with 'require_once' or every file within the Google API PHP client manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [composer](https://getcomposer.org). CI supports [autoloading](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) of third party libraries with composer. Besides, usage of composer is a preferred method to install Google APIs Client Library. In this way you won't need to include the library with `require_once`, all the modules will be loaded automaticly by composer's autoloader.